# Data Races in an AtomicIntegerArray

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomicreference

In the code below:
I am updating `num[1]=0` of an `AtomicIntegerArray` num 1000 times each in 2 threads.

At the end of the 2 threads in main thread ;shouldn't the value of `num[1]` be 2000 as there shouldn't be data races in an `AtomicIntegerArray` .

However I get random values < 2000. Could someone tell me why?

Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerArray;

public class AtomicIntegerArr {

    private static AtomicIntegerArray num= new AtomicIntegerArray(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRun1());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRun2());

        num.set(0, 10);
        num.set(1, 0);

        System.out.println("In Main num before:"+num.get(1));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println("In Main num after:"+num.get(1));
    }

    static class MyRun1 implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                num.set(1,num.get(1)+1);
            }

        }
    }

    static class MyRun2 implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                num.set(1,num.get(1)+1);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Edit: Adding `num.compareAndSet(1, num.get(1), num.get(1)+1);` instead of `num.set(1,num.get(1)+1);` doesnt work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get random values < 2000. Could someone tell me why?

This is called [the lost-update problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

Because, in the following code:

```
num.set(1, num.get(1) + 1);
```

Although each individual operation involved is atomic, the combined operation is not. The single operations from the two threads can interleave, causing updates from one thread to be overwritten with stale value by another thread.

You can use `compareAndSet` to solve this problem, but you have to check whether the operation is successful, and do it again when it fails.

```
int v;
do {
    v = num.get(1);
} while (!num.compareAndSet(1, v, v+1));
```

There's also a method for exactly this purpose:

```
num.accumulateAndGet(1, 1, (x, d)->x+d);
```

**accumulateAndGet(int i, int x, IntBinaryOperator accumulatorFunction)**

> Atomically updates the element at index i with the results of applying the given function to the current and given values, returning the updated value. The function should be side-effect-free, since it may be re-applied when attempted updates fail due to contention among threads. The function is applied with the current value at index i as its first argument, and the given update as the second argument.

Comment: Hi,Luke: Yes the entire operation was not atomic !! My bad !!! As for solving it, i was aware of the looped CompareAndSet but didnt know about the accumulateAndGet method available. Using GetAndIncrement solved it too !! Thanks :) !!

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic race condition. Any time you have a fetch, an operation, and a put, your code is racy.

Consider two threads, both executing `num.set(1,num.get(1)+1)` at roughly the "same time." First, let's break down what the expression itself is doing:

- it fetches `num.get(1)`; let's call this `x`
- it adds 1 to that; let's call this `y`
- it puts that sum in at `num.set(1, y);

Even though the intermediate values in your expression are just values on the stack, and not explicit variables, the operation is the same: get, add, put.

Okay, so back to our two threads. What if the operations are ordered like this?

```
inital state: n[1] = 5
Thread A      | Thread B
========================
x = n[1] = 5  |
              | x = n[1] = 5
              | y = 5 + 1 = 6
y = 5 + 1 = 6 | 
n[1] = 6      |
              | n[1] = 6
```

Since both threads fetched the value before either thread put its added value, they both do the same thing. You have 5 + 1 twice, and the result is 6, not 7!

What you want is [`getAndIncrement(int idx)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html#getAndIncrement-int-), or one of the similar methods that does the get, adding, and putting atomically.

These methods can actually all be built on top of the [`compareAndSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html#compareAndSet-int-int-int-) method you identified. But to do that, you need to do the increment within a loop, trying until the `compareAndSet` returns true. Also, for that to work, you have store that initial `num.get(1)` value in a local variable, rather than fetching it a second time. In effect, this loop says "keep trying the get-add-put logic until it works without anyone else having raced between the operations." In my example above, Thread B would have noticed that `compareAndSet(1, 5, 6)` fails (since the actual value at that time is 6, not 5 as expected), and thus retried. This is in fact what all of those atomic methods, like `getAndIncrement`, do.

Comment: num.set(1,num.get(1)+1);   I was under the impression set would run atomically entirely which is true but before set was actually called; another get could be called in the 2nd thread and then the 2 sets can happen.  getandIncrement does get,increment and set atomically;whereas in my case;this can arise(get happened;again a get happened and then 2 sets).  Thanks Yshavit :)